# Search bar in Table view sends wrong data to another Table View

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, tableview, uisearchbar

[image]I have one tableview containing data that is fed from an Array with 14 entries. I have added a search bar where I can filter this data and this works fine, but when I try to send the filtered data to a second table view, the data that is sent is the count of my filtered data. So if I search something starting with G(13th and 14th place in my array), that brings back two results which is fine but when I choose the first entry off my filtered data(the two results), the data that is passed to the second Table View is the [0] entry(A) of my initial TVC and not the 13th(G12).So depending on the filtered data I always get the first few entries of my initial array.

```
struct ImageForManuf {
           let image: UIImage
           let name: String
           init(nameInit: String) {
               self.name = nameInit
               image = UIImage(named: nameInit)!
           }
       }


     struct SecondTable {
    
    var secondTitle : [String]

    var pic : [UIImage?]
   
}
    
    //for search bar
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
  
    var filteredData: [ImageForManuf]!
    var searching = false

    var firstArray = [ImageForManuf]()
    //we are adding elements on the SecondTable structure
    var secondArray = [SecondTable]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //for search bar
        searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = firstArray
        

        firstArray = [ "A","A2","B3","B4","B5","C6","C7","D8","E9","F10","F11","G12","G13","H14",

        ].map(ImageForManuf.init(nameInit:))
        filteredData = firstArray



secondArray = [SecondTable(secondTitle: ["A1"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "A1")]),
               SecondTable(secondTitle: ["B1","B2","B3"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "B1"),UIImage(named: "B2"),UIImage(named: "B3")]),
               SecondTable(secondTitle: ["C1","C2"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "C1"),pic: [UIImage(named: "C2")]),
               SecondTable(secondTitle: ["D1"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "D1"),
               SecondTable(secondTitle: ["E1"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "E1"),
               SecondTable(secondTitle: ["F1","F2"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "F1"),pic: [UIImage(named: "F2")]),
              SecondTable(secondTitle: ["G1","G2"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "G1"),pic: [UIImage(named: "G2")]),
              SecondTable(secondTitle: ["H1"],
                                  pic: [UIImage(named: "H1")
```

]

This is my TV configuration

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            if searching
            {
               return filteredData.count
            }else{
               return firstArray.count
            }
    }
    
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableTableViewCell

        Cell.textLabel?.textColor = .systemBlue
        Cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        
            if searching
            {
                Cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].name
                Cell.imageManuf?.image = filteredData[indexPath.row].image

            }else{
                Cell.textLabel?.text = firstArray[indexPath.row].name
                Cell.imageManuf?.image = filteredData[indexPath.row].image
            }
        
        
        return Cell
        
    }

    
        //we need to create a variable that can hold the destination view controller
       override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


 if searching {
let row = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row ?? 0
            let destViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController var secondTableArray : SecondTable
            secondTableArray = secondArray[row]
            destViewController.secondTableVcArray = secondTableArray.secondTitle
            destViewController.detailVcArray = thirdArray[row]
        }else{
            let row = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row ?? 0
            let destViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
            
            var secondTableArray : SecondTable
            secondTableArray = secondArray[row]
            secondTableArray created in SecondTableViewController
            destViewController.secondTableVcArray = secondTableArray.secondTitle
            destViewController.detailVcArray = thirdArray[row]
            
        }
 
    }
```

Lastly this is my searchBar configuration

```
 //Mark: Search Bar config
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredData = firstArray.filter({$0.name.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})

        searching = true

        
        
        //to reload the data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

This is the second TVC:

```
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //we are loading the secondArray via the secondTableVcArray
    var secondTableVcArray = [String]()
    //we are loading the thirdArray via the detailVcArray
    var detailVcArray : [DetailView]?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return secondTableVcArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
       
        
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

        //we load the data of the secondTableVcArray to our cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = secondTableVcArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let row = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
            print("Error: problem with second table view or selection")
            return
        }
        guard let dest = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController else {
            print("Error: couldn't find expected DetailsViewController")
            return
        }
        guard let details = detailVcArray else {
            print("Error: data not set for SecondTableViewController")
            return
        }
        dest.displayDetail = details[row]

        
    }


   

}
```

Can somebody help with the row element of my prepareforSeque method and advice the syntax on how to get the indexPath of my firstArray as @vadian suggested? The second condition works fine(not searching) but I don't seem to be able to pull the right item from my DataSource in the searching condition.

Comment: I don't understand... where do you pass filteredArray to the SecondTableViewController? what is secondArray? Can you share the other data model?

Comment: In `prepare(for` you have to consider `searching` like in the other methods. And consider also to use more meaningful names than first..., second..., third...

Comment: @vadian - Good morning, when I don't use the search bar my data pass through like a dream ,it's only when I use the filteredData array that I get this problem.

Comment: In `prepare(for` in the first view controller you get the item from `secondArray` but this is not part of the data source therefore the index cannot match.

Comment: @vadian - Hi Vadian , is there a way to get the index of my first array and add it to the row element? I know that I am useless, I am learning still and there are many things that although I understand them(I understand exactly what you mean) I can't seem to find the solution...

Comment: Nobody – but you – knows how `secondArray` (once again the ordinal naming *first..., second..., third...* is confusing) is related to the data source

Comment: @vadian - Hi vadian, I select a cell on the first TVC that is fed data from the firstArray, a segue is performed to a second TVC that depending on the selection, gives you a list that is fed data from the secondArray. The first Array contains the manufacturer and the secondArray the products under this manufacturer (one manufacturer contains a list of products)and there is a third VC that has the details for each product.When I don't use search everything works fine, the problem arrises when I use the search since a temporary array is formed whith the search entries. Does this make sense?

Comment: @vadian - Will it help if I add a primary key value on my struct and try to pull this value or do you still believe that I can pull the correct value by just adding a condition on my prepare(for . What do you mean by "second array is not part of the datasource" is there a way to make it part of it? I am really confused.